# Sending JSON to privateEndpoint azure with azure function app VNET integration

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-function-app

I have a function app that is reversed proxied to a private endpoint which is also a function app. I'm trying to use this proxy to send JSON to the private endpoint so it can add the JSON to the DB. But for some reason, it doesn't do this, however, when want to read all the data the function app works just fine and sends all the jsons from my DB to the proxied function app and I can see them.
Is it possible to send data through the proxy connection to a private End point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to send data through the proxy connection to a private
> End point?

I had do a test, I create two function app. Function app A uses VNET integration. And I create a proxy in function app to reverse to A.

The result of the test is that if I use the 'get' method, the body will be lost when reverse proxying. But using the 'post' method can get and process data well.

So my conclusion is that the reverse proxy can transmit data, but you need to pay attention to the request method used.